# Hash key value changing to array reference after subroutine in perl

Tags: perl, hash, reference, subroutine

I'm creating keys outside and inside a subroutine on the same hash.  However, after the subroutine, the values in the keys I created before the subroutine is called, are now interpreted as array references.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use module;
use strict;
use warnings;
my %hash;
my $count = 0;

my @array = ("a", "b", "c", "d");

for my $letter (@array) {
    $hash{$letter} = $count;
    $count++;
}

# need "\" to pass in hash otherwise changes
# will get lost outside of subroutine
foreach my $x (sort keys %hash) {
    print "first $hash{$x}\n";
}

module::add_ten(\%hash);

foreach my $p (sort keys %hash) {
    # $hash{$p} is printing array references, but before it was
    # printing the value I desired.  What did the subroutine do?
    print "second $hash{$p} $hash{$p}->{ten}\n";
}
```

and here is the module with the subroutine

```
package module;

sub add_ten {
my $count = 10;
    # this passes the full array as reference
    my ($hash_ref) = @_; # $hash_ref is actually %hash (yes, the % is not a typo)
    my @keys = keys $hash_ref;
    foreach my $ltr (sort keys $hash_ref) {
        $hash_ref->{$ltr} = { ten => $count };
        $count++;
    }
}
1;
```

here is the output:

```
first 0
first 1
first 2
first 3
second HASH(0x7ff0c3049c50) 10
second HASH(0x7ff0c3049bc0) 11
second HASH(0x7ff0c3049b90) 12
second HASH(0x7ff0c3049b60) 13
```

I'm expecting the output to be:

```
first 0
first 1
first 2
first 3
second 0 10
second 1 11
second 2 12
second 3 13
```

I modified my module:

```
package module;

sub add_ten {
    my $count = 10;
    # this passes the full array as reference
    my ($hash_ref) = @_; # $hash_ref is actually %hash (yes, the % is not a typo)
    my @keys = keys $hash_ref;
    foreach my $ltr (sort keys $hash_ref) {
        $hash_ref->{$ltr}{ten}=$count;
        $count++;
    }
}
1;
```

and the main script (needed to comment out use strict to get it to work):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use module;
#use strict;
use warnings;
my %hash;
my $count = 0;

my @array = ("a", "b", "c", "d");

for my $letter (@array) {
    $hash{$letter} = $count;
    $count++;
}

# need "\" to pass in hash otherwise changes
# will get lost outside of subroutine
foreach my $x (sort keys %hash) {
    print "first $hash{$x}\n";
}

module::add_ten(\%hash);

foreach my $p (sort keys %hash) {
    print "second $hash{$p} $hash{$p}{ten}\n";
}
```

But this is what I was trying to get to.

Comment: That comment should read `%$hash_ref is %hash`

Comment: `use module` should be `use Module`, and the module itself should be in `Module.pm` and contain a package statement `package Module`

Answer (score 5):

`$hash_ref` is a reference to `%hash`, so when you change the values of the elements of the hash referenced by `$hash_ref`, you're changing the values of the hash `%hash`.

That means that when you do

```
 $hash_ref->{$ltr} = { ten => $count };
```

You are doing

```
 $hash{a} = { ten => 10 };
```

It should be no surprise that `$hash{a}` no longer contains zero. You'll have to change your data structure. You could use the following:

```
$hash{a}{value} = 0;
$hash{a}{subhash}{ten} = 10;
```

Comment: I want $hash{a} = 0 and $hash{a}{ten} = 10.  But $hash{a} returns a hash reference after the subroutine (which I don't want), before the subroutine $hash{a} returned "0"

Comment: You are doing `$hash{a} = 0; $hash{a} = \%subhash;`, and asking why `$hash{a}` isn't zero. It can only hold one of those two values at a time.

Comment: Added a solution to my answer.

Comment: I see...  I thought I was adding another element to $hash{a} called "ten" such that the new data structure would look like $hash{a}{ten}=10.